# Getting an error with XMLHttpRequest when trying to download blob - gives status of 206 in Firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, firefox, xmlhttprequest

When I try to download an mp4 file (it's only 300K) in Firefox, it gives a `206` status, never `200` and never downloads the full video. It works correctly in Chrome.

```
    var blob;

    //Start the request
    var videoRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Get the Video file from the server.
    videoRequest.open( "GET", "/videos/test.mp4", true );

    //It's a blob (for storing in database)
    videoRequest.responseType = "blob";

    //Listen for when it's done downloading the video data
    videoRequest.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function ()
        {
            //This is never reached!
            if ( videoRequest.status === 200 )
            {
                //Get the data
                blob = videoRequest.response;

                //Store in our database
                ...
            }

            //This is always 206!!
            console.log( videoRequest.status );
        },
        false
    );

    //Start the request
    videoRequest.send();
```

In Chrome, it downloads the full video only returning `200` (never `206`).

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you understand what a 206 is?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, but i never set a range header so i shouldn't be getting that. why is that being sent and how do i handle it?

Comment: can you verify it is being sent?

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you mean? when i run it in chrome, it sends it and gives a 200 status. in Firefox, it sends the 206 and the response header says it's sending all but the last byte! (it said something like bytes: 0-36546754/36546755)

Comment: 0-36546754 is 36546755 bytes, so it's all being sent. I meant, can you see the request headers to see if the request is requesting a range

Comment: Note: I've used your code (with a different URL of course) and firefox works correctly, and does not request a "range" - try disabling any add-ons, see if one of them is messing with your request

Comment: Alternatively, change your code to treat 206 as being correct - in this case, it is correct!

Comment: @JaromandaX What do you mean it's correct? How do I work with a 206 to request the rest of the data?

Comment: `the rest of the data` - according to you, you received _bytes: 0-36546754/36546755_ - which, as I explained is **ALL** the data - so, there is no _rest of the data_ to deal with ... it's odd that you've addressed the last of 3 comments, ignoring the request to check if your firefox is actually making a range request, and try with addons disabled to see if one of them is messing with the request ... you either want help or not, suit yourself

Comment: @JaromandaX But it says there's one more byte. So how could that be all the data? (And I did disable all my addons and it's still occurring) And yes, I want help. Please don't think my confusion is not wanting help. Also, how do I check if firefox is requesting the range?

Comment: bytes 0-1/2 would mean bytes 0 and 1 of 2 ... does that help? to check for headers, in firefox, bring up developer tools network tab (ctrl+shift+Q is the shortcut) - when you see the request for the mp4, click on it, on the right you'll see tabs for headers etc, you should be able to see the request/response headers in there

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, that does help! Thanks.